# How to isolate authentication and user registration in Java/JSP

Tags: servlets, authentication

In RegServlet class, I have a `doGet()` method that overrides the `doStuff()` method. `doStuff()` method takes the user input from an HTML registration form, then connects to the DB, then stores the user input into the DB.

Here is the `doStuff()` method in my RegServlet class:

```
public void doStuff(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException {
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    ...
    String email = request.getParameter("email");

    if(!userName.isEmpty()&&!passWord.isEmpty()) {
        request.setAttribute("userName", userName);
        ...
        request.setAttribute("email", email);

        //connect to DB
        toDB.createConnection();

        //insert information to DB
        toDB.insertNewUser(userName, passWord, lastName, firstName, age, sex, email);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);            
    } else {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
```

If the register button is clicked after everything has been entered correctly, it leads me to a login.jsp page. I am now trying to code the log-in mechanism in order for a user (who possesses username & password stored in the DB) to log in and search and add/drop courses.

I am having a hard time because I am not sure how I should go about this.

How can I isolate user registration and authentication? Should I make another class for session management or just another method in this RegServlet class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your own HTTPServletFilter that check if a user is authenticated:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if ("a user is authenticated") {
        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    } else {
        // authenticate a user
    }
}
```

The link show the basic of HTTPServletFilter: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html#70176

Comment: Thanks, Michael. So should this be implemented in the same class as the `doStuff()` method? Or another class?

Comment: Please look at the link I have added to the answer. HTTPServletFilter is different component from HTTPServlet. `doStuff()` is in HTTPServlet, but `doFilter` is in HTTPServletFilter